# Meta-analysis of two-way interaction effect

Tags: regression, interaction, meta-analysis

I have four different studies, each with the same two continuous predictor variables, $x$ and $z$, and a continuous outcome variable, $y$.

In these studies, I use hierarchical linear regression to analyze the data, and my primary interest is the two-way interaction of $x\times z$ on $y$.

I would like to do an internal meta-analysis of these four studies. Is there a way to get a meta-analytic estimate of the interaction effect ($x\times z$ on $y$)?